# Add dividers for each year on View table

Tags: views, 8

I have a view listing a custom content type by year and quarter (Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter). It's currently listed in a table. I'd like there to be dividers for each year within the table. Simply a row that names the year before going on to the content that fits within that year. Below is an image of the effect I want to achieve.

[image]

I've considered creating a twig template for the view, but I'm not sure how I would be able to check whether an item is the first or last item in a year. I've also considered adding a 'custom text' field but again I'm not sure how I'd make a conditional for that, and I'm not sure how I would be able to turn that into a unique row.

Is there a way to create row dividers in a table view once the year changes, or with any field for that matter?

Comment: Can't you just use the "Grouping field" option in the table settings?

Comment: may be you should try this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11059/how-to-group-views-rows-by-year-using-date-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt, I have done this and giving you exact idea.
I did a task for display node under specific location as you need year.

1. I created taxonomy for location like [image] So if you want to create taxonomy for years and add terms it's upto you.
2. Attach the taxonomy to node as term reference field type.
3. Create a view of that content and add required fields. [image]
4. Check view format setting set the field for grouping . [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Grouping field" option inside view formate settings for year field. Here is example of grouping

## 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828952/drupal-7-views-list-group-by-field?answertab=active#tab-top

## 2. https://www.drupal.org/node/1578512

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to achieve this is by using the Settings option from `Format: Table | Settings`.

Please click on the `Settings` and that will allow you to select the field on which you can group the results. 
But prior to that, you will need to add the respective date field in the fields section of the view.

Add the `Date` field respective to which you need to group the content. Set the `format` of the date to be `year` only, and also select exclude from display.
Further, if you need to display the date in the rows also, select the same field again and set the desired format of the date.

Now, all the fields will be available for grouping in the `Settings` tab. You can now identify and select the `date` field which was formatted as `year` only to get the desired result.

If required, please check a simple [reference](http://www.webbykat.com/2013/05/grouping-year-or-month-and-year-view) blog or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828952/drupal-7-views-list-group-by-field?answertab=active#tab-top).